# Android - Apk size very large after rebuild in Release mode

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, apk, release

I just finished from my Android project on Visual Studio 2017, my `apk` size is `10.5 mb`. I have copied my drawable file content and created new folders for different screen size (`mipmap-xhdpi`, `mipmap-hdpi`..) and pasted the `drawable` file's content inside them then I rebuild the project in the release mode and checked the size of the apk, it is now 24 mb. That's `13.5 mb` increase. So I delete the `mipmap` files I have created then rebuild the project (also in the `release` mode) and then I have checked my `apk` size but it didn't changed it is still `24mb`. I cleaned and rebuild the project several times with no results. So why is that and what I need to do to return to the original size `10.5 mb` ?

**Edit**
I rebuild my project in `Debug` mode, it is `10.5 mb` again. Why the `release` mode is causing this increase in apk size ?

Comment: If you have pasted same images in all drawable folders then whats the use of multiple folders ? Just use a Single folder . To support all screens sizes all drawable folder must contain all icons and images with a pre-defined sizes .

Comment: @ADM Okay, I did, the apk size still `24 mb`

Comment: Which kind of linking you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Each screen size needs its graphics assets, so it's absolutely correct. The difference in size between the `Debug` and `Release` mode is due to several factors, majorly to the fact that in debug we use `Shared Runtime` and `Fast Assembly Deployment` in order to not deploy every time the `MonoRuntime`. 
 Deploying in `Release` you are deploying as well the MonoRuntime and the BCL. 
Linking against all the assemblies helps, but for a more extensive way to optimize the size of your application, I would suggest you have a look at this awesome [gist](https://gist.github.com/jgold6/a1e60e0bb24ccdd2b2b8).

Comment: I used `Sdk Assemblies only` as linker and the file size is 24 mb. Then I have changed the linker to `user and sdk assemblies` the file size is 15 mb now but I am getting an `Unhandled exception` during runtime.

Comment: Yes, Linking against User and Sdk assemblies require more work. You have to Preserve or linkskip the assemblies that are removed by the linker. You can find more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker

Comment: Even I would not put the effort just to save 9mb.. @Wassim01

Comment: Okay but I can't get it: why when I link to `user and sdk assemblies` an exception is thrown ? Is it because it removed a useful piece of code and that's caused the exception. Between 9 mb matters in my opinion :)

Comment: Yes, linking in a very broad way means removing the assemblies. You should check which is the missing part of code and preserve it with the link I gave you in the previous link :)